# Clean install windows 10 keeping the original key

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-10, warranty

So, I have a few questions about a pretty straightforward scenario: I purchased a new laptop - namely, Dell's XPS 15 9550 - which came with Windows 10 Home (x64), and also, as usual, with a lot of other applications and bloatware which I neither like nor need, so I want to format the hard drive and do a clean Windows install.

**Problem 1**: Since I do not have any Windows 10 installation media, how can I reinstall Windows?
**Problem 2**: Since I do not have the Windows serial number that the laptop came with, how do I activate them again?
**Problem 3**: Since this laptop is the property of the company that I am currently working for, and not mine, I am concerned about whether this will void the laptop's warranty. Will it still be under warranty, or will I have to do a complete factory reset before I hand it in?

I thank you all very much in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you even authorized to change your laptop’s software if it’s company property?

Comment: Windows 10 will automatically activate in the case you describe you can skip entering a product key but if you are not authorized to manually remove the bloatware please don't attempt to do this yourself

Comment: @DanielB Yeah, they don't care what I do with it as long as I return it to them in the same state as it was on purchase time - so provided that I don't erase the recovery partition, I guess I can do whatever I want and when the time comes, I just factory reset it and voila.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean, they will automatically activate? How will Microsoft know that it's an original copy and not a pirated one if I do not use the vendor's original installation media - or pretty much any means whatsoever that prove that it's a legit purchase?

Comment: @Ramhound **UPDATE** - unless what Gene suggests below - that the Windows key is embedded into the UEFI system - is indeed the case.

Comment: Yes; I know it is true....Windows 10 will automatically reactiavate on any machine it was activated on in the past.  How Windows 8+ keys work is well documented I expect people not asking that specific question to know they are embedded and automatically detected

Comment: Make your Dell recovery media before you clean install, as clean install  will break the recovery partition....http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN297924?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04#Refresh

Answer (score 1):

> Since I do not have any Windows 10 installation media, how can I reinstall Windows?

You can download a copy officially from Microsoft, using the Media Creation Tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Since I do not have the Windows serial number that the laptop came with, how do I activate them again?

On modern systems, the Windows key is embedded into the UEFI system. Windows will automatically detect this key and should activate without any issues.

> I am concerned about whether this will void the laptop's warranty

Not entirely sure about that one, but I'm very sceptical thinking that reinstalling the OS nullifies your warranty. Wasn't a problem in my support cases (I usually wiped the disk completely before sending the device in). Duplicate question: [Will formatting HD and installing my own OS invalidate the warranty on laptops?](https://superuser.com/questions/88186/will-formatting-hd-and-installing-my-own-os-invalidate-the-warranty-on-laptops)

Comment: Why download a copy of windows? Just go to start menu search, and search for "reinstall windows" and you can reinstall from there to a fresh install with no bloatware installed. The actual setting will be something like "Reset installation"

Comment: @LPChip Tried that, no go - sounds interesting though, could you perhaps provide the exact name of the application?

Comment: @LPChip That will keep the partitioning scheme including recovery partitions eating your precious SSD space, if I'm not mistaken. Good call, though.

Comment: @pazof Settings > Update & security > Recovery > Reset this PC

Comment: I have still not found the time to try all of this, I will get back here as soon as I do.